# How to convert timezone to datetime and ISO 8601 format in python?

Tags: python, django

How to convert a timezone string like `2022-06-23T05:00:00.006417+00:00Z` to datetime and ISO 8601 format?

Comment: Be sure to actually search, the next time :) This question has been asked before. This answer is great, and shows a valid warning. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49784038/3806354 (that fromisoformat doesn't work with arbitrary iso strings)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that already the ISO format?

**To parse it**

Anyway as it is in ISO you can use `datetime.fromisoformat`([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)) to parse it, as it looks to be an iso format.

Following examples from the docs:

```python
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04')
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04T00:05:23')
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 5, 23)
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04 00:05:23.283')
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 5, 23, 283000)
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04 00:05:23.283+00:00')
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 5, 23, 283000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04T00:05:23+04:00')   
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 5, 23,
    tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=14400)))
```

Alternatively, if it's another format you can use `datetime.strptime` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)) given some format

**To format it**

To iso-format it, you can use `datetime.isoformat` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat)).

Following examples from the docs:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> datetime(2019, 5, 18, 15, 17, 8, 132263).isoformat()
'2019-05-18T15:17:08.132263'
>>> datetime(2019, 5, 18, 15, 17, tzinfo=timezone.utc).isoformat()
'2019-05-18T15:17:00+00:00'
```

Comment: Instead of posting a whole bunch of examples, you could just provide an answer to the OP's question, or just flag the question as a duplicate?

Comment: I was trying to, in an indirect way, say "you can easily google that or read the manual", but it's a valid criticism, AlexK :) Sorry about that.